# Merge two collections in Ruby to simplify a code

Tags: ruby

Here is a code in Ruby. I'm just trying to simplify it. Do you have any ideas?

```
def foo
   points = some_collection.map { |item| {:key1 => item.key1, :key2 => item.key2, :key3 => item.key3, :key4=> item.key4} }

   some_collection2.each do |item2|
    points << {:key1 => item2.key1, :key2 => item2.key2, :key3 => item2.key3, :key4=> item2.key4}
   end

   points
end
```

Comment: Looks quite simple to me. What exactly don't you like about this code?

Comment: In the `each`loop, shouldn't you call `item2.method1` instead of `item.method1` or am I missing something?

Comment: @davids, I didn't understand you. There was a typo.

Comment: I mean, you are passing along `|item2|` to the each block, however, inside that block, you are using the variable `item`, not ìtem2`. That's a typo, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the mapping function is the same for both collections in your case.

```
points = (some_collection + some_collection2).map do |item|
  {:key1 => item.method1, :key2 => item.method2, :key3 => item.key4, :key5=> item.key5}
end
```

Comment: Ah, didn't see *that* one. But, it might be just oversimplification of original code.

Answer (score 2):

I would store transformed results of the two collections into two arrays and then just added them together.

```
def foo
   a1 = some_collection.map do |item| 
     {:key1 => item.method1, :key2 => item.method2, :key3 => item.key4, :key5=> item.key5}
   end
   a2 = some_collection2.map do |item|
    {:key1 => item.method1, :key2 => item.method2, :key3 => item.key4, :key5=> item.key5}
   end

   a1 + a2
end
```

Or, if you want, it can even become this

```
def foo
   some_collection.map do |item| 
     {:key1 => item.method1, :key2 => item.method2, :key3 => item.key4, :key5=> item.key5}
   end + some_collection2.map do |item2|
    {:key1 => item.method1, :key2 => item.method2, :key3 => item.key4, :key5=> item.key5}
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even extract a list of keys in a separate array, so you would have:

```
keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4]

points = (some_collection + some_collection2).map do |item|
  Hash[keys.map{|key| [key, item.send(key)]}]
end
```